# Ajax.AjaxLink loader image

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out why the loading image seems like to loop forever when I tried to use the following code based on research:
I include the javascript file: spin.min.js here.
In my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/spin.min.js")"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#link_button").click(function () {
        $("#loading").fadeIn(); 
        var opts = { lines:12, length: 7,width: 4,radius: 10, color: '#000',speed: 1,trail: 60,shadow: false,hwaccel: false};
        var target = document.getElementById('loading');
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target); 
    });
});
</script>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "Edit", new { id = item.tbl_id },new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "Get",InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "edit-div",}, new { @class = "link-list", @id = "link_button" })
<div id="edit-div"></div>
<div id="loading">
       <div id="loadingcontent">
            <p id="loadingspinner">Searching things...</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult History(int id = 0) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    var transaction = db.Transactions_vw.Where(x => x.trans_id == id && x.status == false).OrderByDescending(s => s.trans_id).ToList().Take(3);
    return PartialView("List", transaction);
}
```

When I tried to click the ajax link, it shows the result in the div section but the loading image is still there. It won't stop. This works when I'm using form. There's no problem when I used this in form but in ajax link I got this bug. Any way how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: consider @Guruprasad Rao 's answer but I'd like to advice. put `.ToList` after `.Take(...)` to optimize your query in `db.Transactions_vw.Where(x => x.trans_id == id && x.status == false).OrderByDescending(s => s.trans_id).Take(3).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you are not hiding the loading div once your partial view is returned.** It will be always there once you initialize!! Next where is your `#submitbtn` in the page?

and finally according to what you have followed I can suggest you to include one thing in your page

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
        $("#loading").hide(); 
    }
});
```

So whenever your ajax request gets completed this will be run and loading div will be hidden. Just check for options in `xhr` and `settings` to know about the status of ajax call and do the required operations in your ajaxComplete.